# Modify body's classes before first paint

Tags: javascript, html, css, repaint

this is a long shot and I suspect what I am trying to do is ultimately impossible.

I am trying to implement a dark/light mode switch on my website. The thing is that the site is just static files on S3 and as such there's no server side I have control of in play.

The problem I have run into is loading the correct theme when a new page is loaded, because the value is stored in local storage I need to fetch it and change the value on page load.

My current approach uses an initial class of `hidden` on the body which is changed to `light` or `dark` when `DOMContentLoaded` fires. Unfortunately this still causes one paint to happen before the class is changed. By putting the JS in `<head>` I was able to circumvent the problem in Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox.

The problem with the initial paint happening is that it causes an extremely jarring flashing, especially when dark more is enabled as the screen quickly goes from white to black.

So my question is wether it's possible to somehow change the classes of `body` before `DOMContentLoaded` fires?

Thanks

Comment: This may not completely do what you want, but have you tried setting the dark theme as a default? That way, you could circumvent the white flash.

Comment: I don't want to use the dark theme as the default. I tried setting the initial body color to a value close to middle of the dark background color and the light background color, but ultimately there will always be a case that has the flashing problem.

Comment: Instead of adding the class to the body, try to apply the theme class (`.dark`, `.light`) to the `<html>` tag, with JS, directly in your `<head>` section. That element will already be accessible, unlike the body, which will need more time to load (causing a flash). Try it: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/f3NW1rFL). This page will load with a delay of 1sec to simulate slow loading, turn the screen black, and update every second. I see no flash in any browser.

Comment: A script element immediately after the `<body>` tag should be able to set the class of the body without waiting for DOMContentLoaded. Or in the head you could use document.write() to load the style sheet conditionally. (For the latter idea you would need to split your current style sheet in two though.)

Comment: It seems like @blex's suggestion works nicely :) I'd rather have one stylesheet since I am just doing a few color overrides for each of the light/dark classes.

Comment: @blex could you post an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the class to the body, you can add it to the `<html>` element, from the `<head>` section.

That way, the class will be applied before the body loads. Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        html.dark body{background:black;}
    </style>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('class', 'dark');
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```